# Sorting and storing strings in a Linked List

Tags: java, sorting, linked-list

I just need a hint on how to sort and store strings in a Linked List. The data should not be pre sorted, but assigned to the proper alphabetic order using insertAfter and insertBefore operations. Any help?

Comment: Probably, it is cheating to use `Collections.sort(List<T> list)` and `Collections.sort(List<T> list,  Comparator<? super T> c)`, but definitely worth looking into how they implement that

Comment: If the strings you store are known to be unique you should really be using a `SortedSet` instead (which is an interface; consider using a `TreeSet` for instance). Also, you say "alphabetic order"; what do you make of uppercase vs lowercase etc? What about locale dependent collation order?

Answer (score 0):

Now, if you don't care about n^2 + D runtime, you can do an insertion sort on the linked list. something like

```
If (node.Next < currentString)
{
   Node temp = node.Next;
   node.Next = new Node(currentString);
   node.Next.Next = temp;
}
```